# Count and sort items in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

When the user gives input it puts it in a dictionary. When nothing or blanc is filled in it code should stop and give all the inputs + occurences in the dictionary.

```
nummer = 1
def namen(namen):
    var = 1

    key = {}

    while var == 1:
        invoer = input('Volgende naam: ')
        if invoer != '':
            global nummer
            key[nummer] = invoer
            nummer +=1
        else:

            return key
            break

hey = (namen(5))
```

I tried `counter` and a `for` loop but that doesn't work.
So for instance if input = `h, d, d, hh, a, s

```
`it should give `
h=1
d=2
hh=1
a=1
s=1`
```

Comment: Have a look at [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html?#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks working..

```
key = {}

while True:
    uinp = raw_input('Write something: ')
    print uinp
    if len(uinp) == 0:
        break

    try:
        key[uinp] += 1
    except:
        key[uinp] = 1

print key
```

is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you! Really nice with the try and except.

Comment: The try/except must be used with care... But often is faster and clearer than a more complicated code.. Happy to be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reworking of your code that does what I think you are trying to achieve. It takes advantage of [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the standard  `collections` module.

```
from collections import Counter

def namen():

    bedragen = Counter()

    while True:
        invoer = input('Volgende naam: ')
        if invoer == '':
            break
        bedragen[invoer] += 1
    return bedragen


hey = namen()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed in very beginner friendly python!

Answer (score 0):

If the input is guaranteed to be separated by `,` (comma-space), you can use the following snippet with `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> import collections
>>> input = 'h, d, d, hh, a, s'
>>> collections.Counter(input.split(', '))
Counter({'d': 2, 'a': 1, 'hh': 1, 's': 1, 'h': 1})
```

To get your specific formatting, you can do the following:

```
>>> for k, v in collections.Counter(input.split(', ')).items():
...     print ('{}={}'.format(k, v))
...
a=1
hh=1
s=1
d=2
h=1
```

If you just want to delimit with commas and ignore other whitespace, you can replace `input.split(', ')` in any of the above snippets with `[i.strip() for i in input.split(',')]`.